# Python: reverse a string

Tags: python, list, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

I understand that data in Python (strings) are stored like lists

Example:

```
string1 = "foo"
"foo"[1] = "o"
```

How would I use the list.reverse function to reverse the characters in a string? Such that I input "foo" and get returned back "oof"

Comment: Well, actually is more like a tuple, not string, I mean is inmutable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You normally wouldn't.

```
>>> "foo"[::-1]
'oof'
```

Comment: Thanks, good stuff. TIL extended slices!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
''.join(reversed(myString))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use list.reverse, then you have to do this:

```
c = list(string1)
c.reverse()
print ''.join(c)
```

But you are better using `''.join(reversed('foo'))` or just `'foo'[::-1]`